# Redirect to a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to Mvc. I need to do a redirection to a view. I have a views folder then within it a Rentals folder then inside the Rentals folder is my DisplayInvoiceList.cshtml which I want to display. How can I achieve this?

```
              --Rentals
                --DisplayInvoiceList.cshtml



  [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(RentalCustomerViewmodel ameRentalVm)
            {           
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        ameCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        strResult = ameCmd.Parameters["RETURNVALUE"].Value.ToString();

                        if (strResult == "1")
                        {
                            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                            {
                                conn.Close();
                            }

                            //redirect the page
                            RedirectToAction("DisplayInvoiceList", "Rental");



                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Response.Write(ex.Message);
                    }
                }

                return View();
            }




             [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult DisplayInvoiceList()
            {

                return View();
            }
```

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DisplayInvoiceList()
{
     return View("Rentals/DisplayInvoiceList");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have such redirection line: `RedirectToAction("DisplayInvoiceList", "Rental");`
But you've mantioned that your view is in Rentals folder. So, your controller called `"Rentals"` not `"Rental"`. In that case you should change your line to `RedirectToAction("DisplayInvoiceList", "Rentals");`

In fact, if Actions are in the same Controller, it will be enough to use constructor without controller name: `RedirectToAction("DisplayInvoiceList")`